# Power cycle 3V3 during reboot

Tags: pi-4, power-management

I have read about having the PI4 turn off 3V3 on shutdown via the eeprom settings, WAKE_ON_GPIO=0 and POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=1, and verified that his works on my PI4. I would really like, though, to power cycle the 3V3 on reboot. My use case is similar to another post I came across (https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=253101), namely a sensor (3.3V powered) that can hang occasionally and needs power cycle to recover, and my PI would be in a remote location, not easily power cycled. Is there any way to get the PI to power cycle 3V3 during a reboot?

Comment: Why not just use a relay to control the power to the sensor?

Comment: this is what is called an XY question ... asking about a perceived solution to a problem,  no matter if it is misguided, instead of asking about the problem itself

Comment: I was looking not to add additional HW. So, instead is it possible to 3.3V power the sensor via a GPIO, and control power to the device in that way?

Comment: Powering via a GPIO pin WFM. The sensor pulls little current - devices needing more has I have seen indicated as a possible issue. I added code in my program to power cycle the device via the pin at boot, so if the hanging sensor causes the program to fail it will recover.